# What language mode could I use in vsc to get a syntax highlighting for a key=value event?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this event for example:

```
SperreAusweisCommand(ausweisId=S55007200672, sperrungInput=SperrungInput(lockReason=LK_DELAY_CARD_PRODUCTION_ADDRESS, sperrungsDatum=null, externeReferenz=null), requestContext=RequestContext(auftraggeber=Quelle(typ=BENUTZERID, id=chagai.friedlander@sbb.ch, info=null, kanal=null), ausloesendeAusweisId=None, ausloesendeFotoId=None, novaContext=NovaContext(clientId=NovaClientId(kanalCode=909, leistungsvermittler=11, verkaufsstelle=Didok5(wert=19106), vertriebspunkt=Didok5(wert=19106), verkaufsgeraeteId=236, bearbeiter=None), correlation=NovaCorrelation(correlationId=a006a0bd-a6ce-4009-b05d-00f10b874099, geschaeftsprozessId=Some(b9f9e003-8a14-4656-84d0-5d9baf9979a2))))) returned Ok(Karte(ausweis=Ausweis(ausweisPk=AusweisPk(wert=2782866), ausweisId=S55007200672, status=GESPERRT, ausstellungsDatum=2023-01-23T17:58:04, kundenInfo=KundenInfo(customerId=CustomerId(tkId=TkId(wert=52e80379-f285-44dd-b9aa-509586ed0950), ckm13=247-739-818-4)), aktivierung=Aktivierung(aktivierer=Quelle(typ=SYSTEMID, id=DIGI Wizard, info=null, kanal=null), aktivierungsDatum=2023-01-23T17:58:04.056, activationReason=AC_SALE), deaktivierung=null, sperrStack=SperrStack(sperrungen=List(Sperrung(sperrer=Quelle(typ=SYSTEMID, id=DIGI Wizard, info=null, kanal=null), sperrungsDatum=2023-01-23T17:58:07.227, lockReason=LK_SUSPICION_OF_FALSIFICATION, externeReferenz=null), Sperrung(sperrer=Quelle(typ=BENUTZERID, id=chagai.friedlander@sbb.ch, info=null, kanal=null), sperrungsDatum=2023-01-24T22:39:27.795, lockReason=LK_PHOTO_TOO_OLD, externeReferenz=null), Sperrung(sperrer=Quelle(typ=BENUTZERID, id=chagai.friedlander@sbb.ch, info=null, kanal=null), sperrungsDatum=2023-01-27T09:24:46.806, lockReason=LK_DELAY_CARD_PRODUCTION_ADDRESS, externeReferenz=null), Sperrung(sperrer=Quelle(typ=BENUTZERID, id=chagai.friedlander@sbb.ch, info=null, kanal=null), sperrungsDatum=2023-01-27T09:21:28.424, lockReason=LK_LOSS, externeReferenz=null)), entsperrungen=List()), externeReferenz=ExterneReferenz(prefix=SBB, id=3719236)), kartenSequenzNr=KartenSequenzNr(value=1), fotoId=FotoId(wert=498017), erneuerungsDatum=2026-02-28T00:00, produzent=MOCK, kartenGeneration=2.0, kartenQualitaet=KartenQualitaet(qualityReason=QA_OK, aenderungsDatum=2023-01-23T17:58:04.056), techInfo=KarteTechInfo(mediumId=KarteMediumId(bfed2993fd4b4b39b22128da65c25cc6), transponder=Transponder(transponderUid14443=A044E9E8, transponderUid15693=0517A1072758C352), produktionsId=2023-01-23, produktionsDatum=2023-01-23, publicKey2fa=PublicKey2FA(wert=LfmyeRHZ97OPZK7gS4Y8fF9pqf78HCbyVfSAsCfd0dRHaVUvUTyN0fsdZmmGr0tBhPq6HbZDrzVjzUjf7LasfW567FdgVzpvHv45aDKyBZr2gekrS8cUjNmZy0SwWSBH6tmlnB1IwPHMfTWcADgdg0UouXCyG3mlJbxUQEn7caYwyp75SuWHLzUpuJW23WFlQEhyXZ0xncJHoTVBAhwxjZ8iIhbHpisQA3Xzr5azDYs1TaIBWbABstf0aByh4sN, zertifikatAblaufdatum=2026-01-23), druckInformationen=DruckInformationen(schriftgroesse=9.0), legicId=LegicId(wert=97600608072256), appletVersionen=AppletVersionen(oevVersion=7.0, ppseVersion=2.0, legicVersion=7.7, emvVersion=9.1, fidoVersion=1.9), emvParameter=EmvParameter(ablaufDatum=ExpiryDate(value=2026-02-28))), inUse=true), Vector())
```

I tried json but it does not work that well.

Comment: Removed tag. "Kafka events" are binary, therefore have no "human readable form". Change your (Scala object?) `toString()` output to actually **return JSON** if you really want syntax highlighting _for JSON_.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Python works pretty well, at least when I do that I get the "Go to Bracket" feature to work. I am still getting other errors though so it's not the best solution.